# Ng repeat result does not show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular js, and I tried to understand this, but still doesn't understand why it does not show the result. I'm trying to get the `entry_date` and `remarks`. Here is my array example:-

```
0: {
   name: "James",
   student_branch: {
      0: {
         entry_date: "13 Dec 2016",
         remarks: "Naughty"
      },
      1: {
         entry_date: "13 Dec 2017",
         remarks: "Nice"
      }
   }
   class: "Gems"
}

1: {
   name: "Admiral",
   student_branch: {
      0: {
         entry_date: "13 Dec 2016",
         remarks: "Naughty"
      },
      1: {
         entry_date: "13 Dec 2017",
         remarks: "Naughty"
      }
   }
   class: "Gold"
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, the array shown above is in `studentDetails`,

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in studentDetails">

   <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in studentHeader">
      <!-- Ignore this line -->



      <div ng-repeat="item in customer.student_branch track by $index">
         <span ng-repeat="value in item track by $index">{{value.entry_date}}</span>
         <span ng-repeat="value in item track by $index">{{value.remarks}}</span>
      </div>

   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do u mean "Ignore this line"? The line seems important.

Comment: @blackmiaool that line is just to create column, but anyhow I think I found the solution for it. Thanks!

Comment: show me your `studentHeader` variable

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be using `ng-repeat` where it isn't quite appropriate.

When you use `ng-repeat="item in customer.student_branch track by $index"` the `item` variable will contain objects like this for each iteration:

```
{ entry_date: "13 Dec 2016", remarks: "Naughty" }
```

Then when you use the nested `ng-repeat="value in item track by $index"` the `value`-variable will actually contain the values

```
"13 Dec 2016"
and
"Naughty"
```

So when you try to use e.g. `value.entry_date`, it'll return `undefined` since that is actually equivalent to calling `"13 Dec 2016".entry_date`. So having the inner-most `ng-repeat` is what is causing your problem. You should only really use ng-repeat, when you're actually trying to iterate through a collection.

So the correct code should look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in studentDetails">   
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in studentHeader"><!-- Ignore this line --> 

        <div ng-repeat="item in customer.student_branch track by $index">
            <span>{{item.entry_date}}</span>
            <span>{{item.remarks}}</span>
        </div>    

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you down vote I'd appreciate it if you'd include a comment with a reason so I know what to do differently next time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to some changes like

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in studentDetails">   
    <td>
        <div ng-repeat="item in customer.student_branch track by $index">
            <span>{{item.entry_date}}</span>
            <span>{{item.remarks}}</span>
        </div>    
    </td>
</tr>
```